# Proof Verification: $\tilde{\beta_1}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\beta_1$ obtained by assuming intercept is zero

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

Consider the standard simple regression model $y= \beta_o + \beta_1 x +u$ under the Gauss-Markov Assumptions SLR.1 through SLR.5.
Let $\tilde{\beta_1}$ be the estimator for $\beta_1$ obtained by assuming that the intercept is 0.
Find $E[\tilde{\beta_1}]$ in terms of the $x_i$, $\beta_0$, and $\beta_1$. Verify that $\tilde{\beta_1}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\beta_1$ obtained by assuming intercept is zero. Are there any other cases when $\tilde{\beta_1}$  is unbiased?

Proof:

We need to prove that $E[\tilde{\beta_1}] = E[\beta_1]$

Using least squares, we find that $\tilde{\beta_1} = \dfrac{\sum{x_iy_i}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}}$

Then, $ \tilde{\beta_1} = \dfrac{\sum{x_i(\beta_0 +\beta_1x_i +u)}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}}$

$\implies  \tilde{\beta_1} = \beta_0\dfrac{\sum{x_i}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}} +\beta_1 +\dfrac{\sum{x_iu_i}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}}$

Taking Expectayion on both sides:

$\implies E[\tilde{\beta_1}] = \beta_0E[\dfrac{\sum{x_i}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}}]+ \beta_1 +\dfrac{\sum{E(x_iu_i)}}{E[\sum{(x_i)^2}]}$  (since summation and expectation operators are interchangeable)

Then, we have that $E[x_iu_i]=0$ by assumption (results from the assumption that $E[u|x]=0$

$\implies E[\tilde{\beta_1}] = \beta_0E[\dfrac{\sum{x_i}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}}]+ \beta_1 +0$

Now, the only problem we have is with the $\beta_0$ term.

If we have that $\beta_0 =0$ or $\sum{x_i}=0$, then $\tilde{\beta_1}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\beta_1$/

Can anyone please verify this proof? Also, why don't we write $y= \beta_1x +u$ instead of $y= \beta_0 +\beta_1x +u$ if we're assuming that $\beta_0 =0$ anyway?

Please let me know if my reasoning is valid and if there are any errors.

Thank you.

Comment: "since summation and expectation operators are interchangeable" Yes, you are right. But division or fraction and expectation operators are NOT interchangeable. $E(\frac AB) \ne \frac{E(A)}{E(B)}$.

Comment: Then how do I get around this problem?

Comment: I just found an error. I cannot understand what you want to prove. After "assuming that the intercept is 0", $\beta_0$ appears many times. In regression, generally we assume covariate $x$ is a constant. So $E(x)=x$.

Comment: Since $x_i$'s are fixed in repeated sampling, can I take the $\dfrac{1}{\sum{x_i^2}}$ as a constant and then apply the Expectation operator on $x_iu_i$ ?

Comment: Like $\dfrac{1}{\sum{(x_i)^2}}\sum{E[x_iu_i]}$

Comment: See contents in Answer. It is hard to write math in Comment.

Comment: @a_statistician The TeX markup works almost the same in comments as in answers, like this: $$E(\tilde{\beta_1}) = E\left(\beta_0\dfrac{\sum{x_i}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}} +\beta_1 +\dfrac{\sum{x_iu_i}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}}\right) = \beta_0\dfrac{\sum{x_i}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}} +\beta_1 + \dfrac{\sum{x_iE(u_i)}}{\sum{(x_i)^2}}.$$  Here's a tip: open a new window, navigate to CV, and start asking a new question.  Use the form to see what the TeX markup will look like.  When it's what you want, paste it into your original comment.  Close the new window without posting the question, please!